# Wanted knowledge for Wordpress and a calendar plugin to push events to customers

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api, icalendar

thank you for reading this and trying to help me realize my dream to host a platform where customers can get a paid subscription to one (or more) events. How do I vision this? I'll try to elaborate.

These events are recurring every year but different dates. The best way to describe this is by using an example: schools. Jim has two classes he's attending: math and gym. He needs the class schedule in his phone calender so he's always up to date with changes due to illness, bad weather, etc. So he subscribes to both math and gym and gets push noticifations when changes occur. After this school year Jim managed to graduate for math and continues to go gym classes. He's subscription does not recure for math and he's access should be provoked. But he pays for the gym subscription so this one does recure and he continues to receive updates.

As I'm not a hard core programmer I'm using Wordpress and so far I managed to get things working. It's mainly manual labour though.

The idea is that the customer goes to the website, order and pays for math and gym and gets a downloadlink for the ical.

Challenging here is: making the ical link unique so only Jim can subscribe and not share it with Jane (maybe using his e-mail as identifier). I haven't found a good way to do so.
Besides the unique identifier I haven't figured out if and how to inform the customer in case of changes to the schedule (e.g. math is rescheduled to 11am instead of 10am.

Wishfull thinking for the future
If this is running smoothly I'd like to grant the math professor and gym teacher to "own" the calendar and fill the calendar at the start of the semester and keep up with changes themselves. This option would be something to consider from the start to avoid architectural changes later.

So, you went trough my explaination of my vision and I'm hoping your able to point me in the right direction. For now, the budget to hire a programmer to build a fully customized website is not an option. Maybe small adjustments to plugins already on the market.

I'd love to hear from you!

Best,
Bas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.